# Filament File upload with action

Tags: laravel, file, upload, laravel-excel, laravel-filament

I have a Filament resource and I want to import data to the Model using the file upload and laravel-excel feature.

```
Action::make('import')->label('Import Data')
                ->form([
                    FileUpload::make('attachment')
                        ->directory('form-attachments')
                        ->acceptedFileTypes(['text/csv', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'])
                        ->visibility('private'),
                ])
                ->action(fn(): string => route('sources.import')),
```

This created the button in list page and file upload works correctly, but the action url seems to be not linked. On submitting the form, the modal closes, no route action is get called.

How can I call a route on succesful form submit in filament?

Comment: Do you mean it's not uploading on respacted route that you are defining in `->action()`?

Comment: @MiteshRathod yes, the route is never reached

Comment: can you try `->submit()` instead of `->action()` ?